# If formula between ranges and with several possible tags

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Would anybody happen to know if possible to build the following formula?

(Dont know if its too complex to actually do through an IF function)

If "good" and number in second column is = to 1,4 or below then give X percentage discount. If between 1,41 and 1,47 then give X percentage discount. If between 1,48 and 1,57 then give X percentage. If equal to 1,58 or above then give X

If "Fair" and number in second column is = to 1,4 or below then give X percentage discount. If between 1,41 and 1,47 then give X percentage discount. If between 1,48 and 1,57 then give X percentage. If equal to 1,58 or above then give X

If "Attention" and number in second column is = to 1,4 or below then give X percentage discount. If between 1,41 and 1,47 then give X percentage discount. If between 1,48 and 1,57 then give X percentage. If equal to 1,58 or above then give X

If "Clearance" then give 80% discount

Comment: Yes it is possible. Better get started.

Comment: "Good", "Fair" and "Attention" do basically the same?!?

Answer (score 1):

Make a table that has the values:

[image]

Then use an INDEX/MATCH/MATCH formula:

```
=INDEX(G:K,MATCH(A2,G:G,0),MATCH(B2,$G$1:$K$1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your previous question, try the below formula

```
=IF(C2<=1.4,IF(B2="Good",0.1,IF(B2="Fair",0.2,IF(B2="Attention",0.3,0.8))),
IF(AND(C2>=1.41,C2<=1.47),IF(B2="Good",0.12,IF(B2="Fair",0.22,IF(B2="Attention",0.32,0.8))),
IF(AND(C2>=1.48,C2<=1.57),IF(B2="Good",0.15,IF(B2="Fair",0.25,IF(B2="Attention",0.35,0.8))),
IF(B2="Good",0.18,IF(B2="Fair",0.28,IF(B2="Attention",0.38,0.8))))))
```

Format `Column D` as Percentage. Percentages assigned in the formula are based on the corresponding conditions listed in the image below.

[image]